# add Button and event at runtime Angular5

Tags: angular

I am trying to ad a Button and event to it at runtime. 
e.g.

```
  str1 = `
    <button type="button" (click)='alert1()'>Click Me!</button>
  `
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  safeStr() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.str1);
  }

  alert1() {
    alert('me')
  }
```

In template :: `<span [innerHTML]="safeStr()"></span>`

The button is rendering but click event not working. Can anyone help please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2 might help

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is interpreted by the browser, that's why you see the button. The JS however is generated at compile time. You should do something much simpler : hide the button if not needed, with a code that looks like :

```
<button *ngIf="isButtonDisplayed" type="button" (click)="alert1()">Click Me !</button>
```

And in component, add a `isButtonDisplayed` boolean value that you switch from false to true at runtime.

Comment: The whole button tag is coming as an string from a service. So nothing at design time.

Comment: Ho, that's a point you did not mention. When you say that the button is coming from service, what exactly you mean ? Does your service get this code from a backend ? Or does the service construct it based on some logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that what you are trying to achieve is to just show the button.
In that case you should use `*ngIf`

Like this

template:

```
<button *ngIf="someBooleanCondition" type="button" (click)='alert1()'>Click Me!</button>
```

If you really need to inject template in runtime, it should be still possible, at least according to this article - https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/

However it seems like a really weird and complicated scenario, to load buttons from external service. Using `*ngIf` together with some config object coming from that service would be imho much easier.

Comment: The whole button tag is coming as an string from a service. So nothing at design time.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2/4/5 doesn't process HTML added dynamically.Click event will not work.